# Start New Terminal with Bash Script

Tags: linux

I am trying to create a BASH script that will first open a new terminal, then run the rest of the script in that new terminal. If possible I would like this to be in one complete script.

I do not want konsole -e as this would require me making a seperate script ( I think)

Comment: The `-e` argument to (for example) `gnome-terminal` will be useful.

Comment: You are incorrect about the separate script thing. (Check the description of `-e` on the [konsole man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/konsole.1.html))

Comment: So if I did this:  konsole -e (rest of bash script below) it would execute the script in the new konsole window?

Comment: I just made a permanent alias using alias='konsole -e "~/Desktop/script"'. Its not really the solution I was looking for though

Answer (score 2):

`what have you tried - that was great`

It is not that complicated to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ ! -f /tmp/$(basename $0) ] && cp $0 /tmp/ && konsole -e $0 && exit
rm /tmp/$(basename $0)
   # --- put your code here --- #

     echo "TESTING"

   # --- put your code here --- #

sleep 3s
```

What it does, it copy script to /tmp directory and run konsole -e over source script, removes temporary file, check if file does not exists and after execution of your code, sleeps 3 seconds then exits.

You could even mod /tmp/ script and run over it.

Comment: +1 Your answer is exactly the solution I was looking for. I would like to understand it better. Why is /tmp/ involved? How does this work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "<your script/*eg. ./bashfile.ext*/>" | xterm
```